# What is the use of System.Drawing.Drawing2D.Matrix class?

Tags: c#, graphics, matrix

If the `Graphics` class handle all the functionality as `Matrix` ?

Comment: I'd put money on the graphics class calling the matrix class

Comment: The underlying functionality for the graphics class transformations will use the matrix class. Also you may want custom transforms

Comment: are you sure you are using the correct matrix when using matrix class?

Comment: [These](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Examples_in_2D_graphics)

Answer (score 3):

No, with the `Graphics` class you can *perform* specific transformations using methods such as [`ScaleTransform`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhc2xxtx.aspx), but the `Matrix` class represents the transformation itself - which is why the [`Graphics.Transform`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.transform.aspx) property is of type `Matrix`.

Suppose you want to perform the same transformation on multiple `Graphics` objects, without the point at which the transformation is *applied* being code which should know what the transformation it. Or suppose you want to combine different transformations in different stages of a pipeline... how would you represent that transformation without `Matrix`? You *could* remember a bunch of delegates applied to a `Graphics` object, but that seems a bit longwinded compared with the natural matrix approach.